# Refactor this function to reduce its Cognitive Complexity for if else condition

Tags: javascript, react-native, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, sonarlint

I'm getting error in sonar for cognitive complexity, find my code and attached screenshot for more reference. Please help me to resolve this

```
 useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused && isLoggedIn) {
      getProfileData();
    }
    if (isFocused) {
      dispatch(rewardsLandingScreenTracker());
    }
  }, [dispatch, getProfileData, isLoggedIn, isFocused]);
```

[image]

Can someone also update me what will be the solution in case of ternary operator like

```
  const savedPrice =
    (actualPrice ? getConvertedPrice(actualPrice) : 0) -
    (proPrice ? getConvertedPrice(proPrice) : 0);
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You may rewrite it as:

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (isFocused) {
        if (isLoggedIn) getProfileData();
        dispatch(rewardsLandingScreenTracker());
    }
}, [dispatch, getProfileData, isLoggedIn, isFocused]);
```

or

```js
useEffect(() => {
    if (!isFocused) return
        
    if (isLoggedIn) getProfileData();
    dispatch(rewardsLandingScreenTracker());
}, [dispatch, getProfileData, isLoggedIn, isFocused]);
```

The second one may raise lint error on inconsistent return (depends  on your linter settings). Then you'll have to add explicit `return` at the end of the callback function.

Comment: Ok, let me try and I've updated my question and added for turnery operator too, Can you please help me in case of turnery operator

Comment: If `n ? convert(n) : 0` is a common behavior just movie it into the `convert` function and rewrite it as `convert(n) - convert(m)`

Comment: Thank you, can you please update this same for above code, I'll refer same for other